# Sending CSV File from Microsoft Data Factory Lakehouse Environment to External Server via SFTP?

Tags: azure-data-factory, microsoft-fabric

I'm currently working on a project where I need to transfer a CSV file from my Microsoft Data Factory Lakehouse environment to an external server using SFTP. I've been exploring the documentation and experimenting with various approaches, but I'm still encountering some challenges.

Does anyone have experience with this specific scenario? Could you please guide me on the steps or provide any insights into how I can accomplish this task efficiently within the Data Factory environment?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a CSV file from Microsoft Data Factory Lakehouse to an external server via SFTP, follow the procedure below:

First, create a linked service for Microsoft Data Factory Lakehouse with the required details, as shown below:

[image]

Next, create a dataset with the linked service mentioned above. Then, create a linked service for the SFTP server as shown below:

[image]

Create a dataset with the linked service above and use the copy activity to copy the files. For more information, you can refer to the following Microsoft documents:

- [Copy and transform data in Microsoft Fabric Lakehouse - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-microsoft-fabric-lakehouse?tabs=data-factory)
- [Configure SFTP in a copy activity - Microsoft Fabric | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-sftp-copy-activity#destination)

After copying the file from Microsoft Data Factory Lakehouse to the SFTP server, copy it to the external server according to your requirements.